# how to convert datetime value to zulu time zone format in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

the current value i have when fetched from database is

```
2018-02-13T12:36:00 ;
```

//but i need it to be convert like below (where z and the end denotes zulu timezone)

```
2018-02-13T12:36:00Z ;
```

Note :i am storing the value in a datetime variable and i dont want this in a string format.i tried converting it to string and append Z to it but it
changes the format like this which is not expected result.Any help is appreciated

```
2/13/2018 12:36: PMZ
```

Comment: The value may already be a DataTime object so you do not need any conversion.  The PC may just be displaying the Time in a different format but the actual object is a DateTime number

Comment: `DateTime.SpecifyKind` or `.ToUniversalTime()` may be what you are looking for

Comment: If you realize that Zulu time is UTC, there are many many questions regarding how to display a DateTime value as UTC; search the site, and have your pick of the available answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is

```
.ToUniversalTime()
```

it converts the date time to Zulu time zone format as it is a part of UTC Time Zone(Zulu time zone is -UTC +0 )

The example mentioned in  [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx)  MSDN article did not mention about 'Z'(Zulu time zone indication) but this method does convert to Zulu time zone.

Comment: Be careful with this.  Depending on `DateTime.Kind`, it may assume your input value is in *local time*.

Comment: But if you convert that ToString() it comes out as yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss. Where is the Zulu format?